# Conversion by constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, copy-constructor, implicit-conversion

Class X -> converted to Y by two ways 1) constructors, and 2) by conversion functions.
I understood the single argument constructor is used for conversion.

In the specification:

> An implicitly-declared copy constructor is not an explicit constructor; it may be called for implicit type conversion.

Question:

So, that means not only single argument constructor is used for the conversion, but also copy constructor?. If so, which scenario it is used?. any snippet of sample code?

Kindly bear with me if the question is very basis.

Comment: The copy-constructor IS a single-argument constructor.  But it doesn't change the type, so I don't know why anyone would call it a "conversion".

Comment: I'm pretty sure my wife will get upset if I "bare with" you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicitly-declared copy constructor cannot use for conversions, since it's `copy-ctor`, that has declared as `T(const T&)` or `T(T&)`.

draft n3337 par 12.8 C++ standard.

> 8 The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class X will have the
>   form X::X(const X&) if — each direct or virtual base class B of X has
>   a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type const B& or const
>   volatile B&, and — for all the non-static data members of X that are
>   of a class type M (or array thereof), each such class type has a copy
>   constructor whose first parameter is of type const M& or const
>   volatile M&.119 Otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy constructor
>   will have the form X::X(X&)

Since copy c-tor is not explicit you can use such code

```
struct So
{
};

int main()
{
    So s = So();
}
```

If `copy-ctor` is explicit you could use only initizaliation like `So s((So()));`

Comment: It can by called a conversion from T to T for the sake of generality.

Comment: @SergeyK. "can be" is the same as "is". Is this a conversion or not?

Comment: @curiousguy: check the .pdf in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Copy constructor is not an explicit constructor, so it will be used wherever possible. Copy constructor will "convert" only from the same type, so it is not a conversion in the full sense. However, for the sake of generality it is handy to call it one.

Read this paper: http://www.keithschwarz.com/cs106l/winter20072008/handouts/180_Conversion_Constructors.pdf if you want more details on conversion constructors.

Comment: "_Copy constructor is not an explicit constructor, so it will be used wherever possible._" And an explicit constructor will be used wherever impossible.

Comment: @curiousguy: so they are pretty same, aren't they?

Answer (score 2):

It basically means that you can do:

```
struct A {};
A a;
A b = a;
```

If the copy constructor was marked explicit that would fail to compile. You can test it by adding: `explicit A( A const & ) {}` to the struct and recompiling the program.

Answer (score 1):

An implicit copy constructor is one that the compiler writes for you. It always has the form

```
T(const T&);
```

This means that any object which has a conversion operator to `const T&` can be implicitly copied, even if this isn't what you wanted. The most common way to trigger this is to make a copy to a base class from a derived class; this is called object slicing because the copy won't have the same type as the original and will probably lose some important properties or behavior.

Comment: Not always. 12.8 par clause 8 n3337 draft.

Comment: @ForEveR, thanks for pointing that out - I didn't know there were exceptions. I'm still having a hard time imagining what the practical edge cases are from reading the standard.

Comment: @Mark: Basically, if your class contains an `auto_ptr` (why would you, since `unique_ptr` was added?), then your implicitly-generated "copy constructor" will have move semantics.

Comment: Can you show a use case for this explicit constructor? What error does it prevent?